# Running single test file on multiple devices at the same file

Tags: grid, appium

I want to run same test method on multiple device at the same time.
I have already achieved running 2 different test scripts on multiple device at the same time but facing difficulty in running same scripts at same time.
Can we create 1 test script using multiple appium instances at the same time?
Is this scenario is possible? Or we can only run different test cases in parallel?

Comment: Anyone achieved this?

Comment: Do you mean having test cases that refer to two or more devices that interact?
If so, I am looking for a solution for exactly this.